# Kubernetes initial password (GCP)? (not using kops?)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-dashboard

Generally you can use `kops get secrets kube --type secret -oplaintext`, but I am not running on AWS and am using GCP.

I read that `kubectl config view` should show you this info, but I see no such thing (wondering if this has to do with GCP serviceaccount setup, am also using GKE).

The `kubectl config view` returns something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://MY_IP
  name: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
    user: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
  name: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
current-context: MY_CONTEXT_NAME
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: 2019-02-27T03:20:49Z
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

Neither **Username**=>`Admin` or **Username**=>`MY_CLUSTER_NAME` worked with **Password**=>`MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sh
gcloud container clusters describe ${CLUSTER} \
--flatten="masterAuth"
[--zone=${ZONE}|--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

It's possible that your cluster has basic authentication (username|password) *disabled* as this authentication mechanism is discouraged.

An alternative mechanism provided with Kubernetes Engine is (as shown in your config) is to use your `gcloud` credentials to get you onto the cluster.

The following command will configure `~/.kube/config` so that you may access the cluster using your `gcloud` credentials. It looks as though this step has been done and you can use `kubectl` directly.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${CLUSTER} \
[--zone=${ZONE}|--region=${REGION}] \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

As long as you're logged in using `gcloud` with an account that's permitted to use the cluster, you should be able to:

```
kubectl cluster-info
kubectl get nodes
```